# PrestaShop create new field on Address

Tags: prestashop

Hy,

I have a question where i can add a new field after Company field because i can't find anything for this

Adress link : http://prestashop/address

[image]

Comment: You have to edit template files, controller and class. Or pick a module :)

Comment: in your_theme/address.tpl, but as sarcom said you need to add it to Address.php class and AddressController.php

Comment: Thanks  tarek it works ,but i must in database on address_format for diferent country to works